# SQL Server Reports Builder - Week Number from Today()

Tags: sql-server, week-number, datepart

I am trying to create a calculated field in SQL Server Reports Builder of which the output is Week Number (e.g. 1, 12, 32, 45, etc...) and am using the following expression:

`=DatePart("ww",Today())`

I am getting a result of "99".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Roman Pelepei has a great [Article](http://rpelepei.blogspot.com/2011/02/datepart-function-in-ssrs.html) on this.

This should do the trick.

`=DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Today())`

You may have to use `Now()` instead of `Today()` but it will work all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try `= DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())`